# Scenario where DHCP static lease AND static IP (both with same IP) on same machine?

Tags: dhcp, tcpip, static-ip

OK the obvious answer is that "this is stupid", but please read the scenario.
Let say, we have a very sensitive piece of equipment (like an alarm system), that we want to eliminate as many possibilities of loosing connectivity to it, as possible.

- I want to assign a DHCP lease so that I am sure it will get the IP I want EVEN if the system loses its configuration (which is NOT uncommon for lower-level TCP/IP-enabled appliances).
- I want to assign a static IP, so that even if DHCP service is down for whatever reason, equipment still gets the same IP.

...so... I know I can do it (there is nothing stopping us), but will it rise any network red flags?
I suspect no, because:

- If static IP works, the equipment will not make a DHCP request at all and will immediately get the proper IP, even if DHCP is dead.
- If static IP fails (equipment resets to factory settings), DHCP request will take place and still get same IP.
- There is no real IP conflict. Same device, same IP, same MAC.

So, your feedback on this?

Comment: set a dhcp reservation for it.  it will use dhcp and always get the same address.

Answer (score 2):

DHCP reservation is what you are looking for.  It is also known as static DHCP assignment and IP address reservation.  By entering the MAC address of your device into the DHCP reservation list, the device will *always* be assigned the designated IP address, regardless if it is dynamic.  Check the documenation for whatever device you have that is providing DHCP to find out how to configure it.